# textarea typing speed issue in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

I have created one textarea for quote generate purpose. whatever i write in textarea it display as preview in div using onkeyup jquery event. it looks like it working good in laptop and pc. but slow down typing speed in mobile browse like 2 to 3 second delay. please help to solve this bug.

this is my textarea where i am writing something

```
 <textarea autofocus class="form-control Whiteboard" name="poster_write" id="poster_write" cols="45" rows="13"></textarea>
```

jquery code to write text onkeyup

```
  $("#poster_write").keyup(function() {

        $("#generate_quote").show();
        var pw = $("#poster_write").val();
        var comment = $.trim($('#poster_write').val());


                $("#poster").html('"' + pw + '"');



    });
```

Comment: You might be doing something on key press event. maybe a ajax call which is synchrounous?

Comment: Show us your code, so that we can find your problem.

Comment: please check i have included code